# How to merge two tables together and keep all the records that match and do not match-Oracle SQL

Tags: sql, oracle, join, oracle11g

I have two tables that I am trying to merge together to create a joined output of them both.

Here is how my tables are structured:

Table 1:

| date | type_s | calls | declines |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 09-SEP-21 | insurance | 500 | 600 |
| 09-SEP-21 | roadside | 66 | 60 |
| 09-SEP-21 | AAA | 34 | 700 |
| 09-SEP-21 | retail | 1 | 650 |

Table 2:

| date | type_s | cnt |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 09-SEP-21 | insurance | 5 |
| 09-SEP-21 | AAA | 3 |
| 09-SEP-21 | retail | 79 |

How do I get my output to be like this:

| date | type_s | calls | declines | cnt |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 09-SEP-21 | insurance | 500 | 600 | 5 |
| 09-SEP-21 | roadside | 66 | 60 | 0 |
| 09-SEP-21 | AAA | 34 | 700 | 3 |
| 09-SEP-21 | retail | 1 | 650 | 79 |

**Notice how in table 2, roadside is not present because there is no data for that type. I am trying to merge them together to keep all records, even if data in column 'type_s'  from table 1 is not present in table 2. In that case, just put 0 as the cnt for that type.**

here is my code so far:

```
with t2 as
(select DATE_TIME , type_s, calls, declines
 from table_1
 ),
CD as
(
SELECT 
DATE_TIME, type_s, CNT
FROM table2
),
DD AS(
SELECT TO_DATE(current_date - 1) AS chart_date,
type_s,
calls,
declines
FROM t2),
GG As
(
SELECT 
DD.chart_date ,
DD.type_s,
DD.calls,
DD.declines,
CD.CNT
FROM CD,DD
WHERE CD.type_s= DD.type_s)
select CHART_DATE,type_s,calls,declines,cnt
from GG;
```

My code runs fine but it doesnt give me the output I desire (view below). It excludes the roadside row from table 1.

| date | type_s | calls | declines | cnt |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 09-SEP-21 | insurance | 500 | 600 | 5 |
| 09-SEP-21 | AAA | 34 | 700 | 3 |
| 09-SEP-21 | retail | 1 | 650 | 79 |

Any ideas or suggestions as to how to fix my code in order to create my desired output? Any help  would be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like an outer join with a `NVL` function. Sample data in lines #1 - 12, query begins at line #13.

```
SQL> with
  2  table1 (datum, type_s, calls, declines) as
  3    (select date '2021-09-09', 'insurance', 500, 600 from dual union all
  4     select date '2021-09-09', 'roadside' ,  66,  60 from dual union all
  5     select date '2021-09-09', 'AAA'      ,  34, 700 from dual union all
  6     select date '2021-09-09', 'retail'   ,   1, 650 from dual
  7    ),
  8  table2 (datum, type_s, cnt) as
  9    (select date '2021-09-09', 'insurance',  5 from dual union all
 10     select date '2021-09-09', 'AAA'      ,  3 from dual union all
 11     select date '2021-09-09', 'retail'   , 79 from dual
 12    )
 13  select a.datum, a.type_s, a.calls, a.declines, nvl(b.cnt, 0) cnt
 14  from table1 a left join table2 b on a.datum  = b.datum
 15                                  and a.type_s = b.type_s
 16    /

DATUM      TYPE_S         CALLS   DECLINES        CNT
---------- --------- ---------- ---------- ----------
2021-09-09 insurance        500        600          5
2021-09-09 AAA               34        700          3
2021-09-09 retail             1        650         79
2021-09-09 roadside          66         60          0

SQL>
```